# Почему не срабатывает оператор case?

Tags: pascal

```
program lb3_2;
uses crt;
var
  x:byte;    
begin
  readln(x);
  1:writeln('Понедельник');
  2:writeln('Вторник');
  3:writeln('Среда');
  4:writeln('Четверг');
  5:writeln('Пятница');
  6:writeln('Суббота');
  7:writeln('Воскресенье');
end.
```

Comment: `case x of ... end;`

Answer (score 2):

Вы неправильно задаете `case` (вы его вообще забыли указать!).

В общем виде он должен выглядеть вот так:

```
  case x of
    1: .. ;
    2: .. ;
    ..
    7: .. ;
  end;
```

Правильный код вы, надеюсь, напишите сами.